# Obtener informacion de usuario con comandos APDU - Login

Tags: c#

Estoy buscando como implementar comandos `APDU` para obtener datos de un `smartCard`, en particular los datos del usuario, desde **C#**. La meta que tengo es hacer una simulación de un Login.

Mi lector es un:

> Athena ASEDrive IIIe Combo BIO 0

Tengo entendido que usa `PCSC`, logro hacer que reconozca el lector, y puedo conseguir el `ATR` del mismo. Pero hasta ahí quedo, no se por donde empezar.

Agradeceria me den alguna guia.

Gracias

Answer (score 1):

Este ejemplo lo encontré en https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/system.security.cryptography.cspparameters(v=vs.110).aspx

HE probado que funciona, quizás te ayude. 
Mi problema, dando vueltas a lo mismo, es como hacer para que no sea dependiente de un modelo concreto, en mi caso "Bit4id Universal Middleware Provider" sino genérico.

```
   private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // To idendify the Smart Card CryptoGraphic Providers on your
        // computer, use the Microsoft Registry Editor (Regedit.exe).
        // The available Smart Card CryptoGraphic Providers are listed
        // in HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider.


        // Create a new CspParameters object that identifies a 
        // Smart Card CryptoGraphic Provider.
        // The 1st parameter comes from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider Types.
        // The 2nd parameter comes from HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Cryptography\Defaults\Provider.
        CspParameters csp = new CspParameters(1, "Bit4id Universal Middleware Provider");
        csp.Flags = CspProviderFlags.UseDefaultKeyContainer;


        // Initialize an RSACryptoServiceProvider object using
        // the CspParameters object.
        RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(csp);

        // Create some data to sign.
        byte[] data = new byte[] { 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7 };

        txtPath.Text += ("Data          : " + BitConverter.ToString(data)) + System.Environment.NewLine;

        // Sign the data using the Smart Card CryptoGraphic Provider.
        byte[] sig = rsa.SignData(data, "SHA1");

        txtPath.Text += ("Signature : " + BitConverter.ToString(sig)) + System.Environment.NewLine;

        // Verify the data using the Smart Card CryptoGraphic Provider.
        bool verified = rsa.VerifyData(data, "SHA1", sig);

        txtPath.Text += ("Verified      : " + verified) + System.Environment.NewLine;

    }
```